# Interview Question about REST API GET vs POST PUT.. Why can not I use GET for Updating or Creating resource.?

Tags: rest

This was one of the question asked in interview about GET method in Rest API.

Lets say I have GET method which will takes all the parameter for updating the resource and creating the resource if not exists. Also I mention that, those parameters are optional, if none specified then i will just return the list of existing resources like list of Accounts.

I know HTTP verbs like GET for fetch existing resource, PUT for updating the existing resource, POST for creating new resource and Delete for deleting existing resource.

The main question from the interviewer is where it will go wrong if we use GET method for all the purpose. or if we use PUT method for creating and updating the existing resource.

Any idea ?

Comment: technically it doesn't matter which HTTP method you are using. You can update the resource with GET as well as delete the resource with POST. It's totally dependent on the server side. Using certain methods for certain actions is nothing else but a convention

Comment: ok.. but wanted to know still where it can go wrong if we keep PUT for update and Create. i wanted to understand the interviewer point of view.